# json response being returned is not recognised

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, asp-classic

I have a production and tesing environment of our website www.phmotorcycles.co.uk/parts/brakes.html.  ON the right hand side of the page there are a set of filter controls.  Now in the test environment this works perfectly.

On page load a call is made to an ASP page that returns a JSON response from the database:

`[{"value":"ktm"}]`

The function call is as follows:

```
function loadFilters(p,l,c) {
$.post('../supportScripts/productFilters.asp',{
    level: l,
    productManufacturer: $("#partMan").val(),
    productGroup: p,
    bikeModel: $("#partBM").val(),
    modelYear: $("#partMY").val(),
    ajax: 'false'}, function(data) {

        var sel = $("#" + c);
        var s = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        sel.empty();
        sel.append('<option value=\'0\'>Please Select</option>');
        for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
            sel.append('<option value="' + s[i].value + '">' + s[i].value.toUpperCase() + '</option>');
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I am getting is on the for loop as firefox reports s as being null.

I have compared all my code in both environments and they are identical as to are the stored procedures on the database.

This one has stumped me for some time, I have even run it through fiddler and the request headers and responses are the same up until the point it breaks on the live server.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might go about and fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vKgdL/ works Are you sure, that data looks exactly like: `[{"value":"ktm"}]`?

Comment: Is value of data the same on both server?

Comment: Yes it is so the response is exactly the same in both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `jQuery.parseJSON`.  Your server is returning `Content-type: application/json`, so jQuery is parsing it for you.  It uses the `Content-type` to "Intelligently Guess" the return type of your AJAX call.

What you *should* do is pass a fourth parameter to `$.post`, `'json'`.  This tells jQuery that you are expecting JSON, and to parse it for you even if the `Content-type` is wrong.

```
function loadFilters(p,l,c) {
    $.post('../supportScripts/productFilters.asp',{
        level: l,
        productManufacturer: $("#partMan").val(),
        productGroup: p,
        bikeModel: $("#partBM").val(),
        modelYear: $("#partMY").val(),
        ajax: 'false'
    }, function(data) {
        var sel = $("#" + c);
        sel.empty();
        sel.append('<option value="0">Please Select</option>');
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].value.toUpperCase() + '</option>');
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why it wasn't working in the production environment and it does in the test environment?

Comment: @GrahamCole: What `Content-type` was the test environment sending?  If it wasn't `application/json` (it was probably `text/html`), then jQuery wouldn't parse it for you, and it would've returned you the raw string instead of an object.

Comment: right ok i will check that when I get into the office in the morning.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! :-D  This code should work in both environments :)